# cypher get relationships between same nodes,but lose some relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

data set:
neo4j-sh (?)$ START n = node(*) MATCH n-[r]-m RETURN n,r,m;
==> +---------------------------------------------+ 
==> | n          | r                 | m          | 
==> +---------------------------------------------+ 
==> | Node[1]{}  | (2)-[1:KNOWS]->(1)| Node[2]{} | 
==> | Node[1]{}  | (3)-[2:KNOWS]->(1) | Node[3]{} | 
==> | Node[2]{} | (2)-[1:KNOWS]->(1) | Node[1]{} | 
==> | Node[2]{} | (3)-[0:KNOWS]->(2) | Node[3]{}  | 
==> | Node[3]{} | (3)-[0:KNOWS]->(2) | Node[2]{}  | 
==> | Node[3]{} | (3)-[2:KNOWS]->(1) | Node[1]{} | 
==> +---------------------------------------------+ 
==> 6 rows 
==>  
==> 0 ms

cypher query:
neo4j-sh (0)$ start x=node(1,2,3),y=node(1,2,3) match x-[r]-y return id(x),id(y) order by id(x) desc;
    ==> +---------------+ 
    ==> | id(x) | id(y) | 
    ==> +---------------+ 
    ==> | 1    | 2     | 
    ==> | 1    | 3     | 
    ==> | 2     | 1    | 
    ==> | 3     | 1    | 
    ==> +---------------+ 
    ==> 4 rows

in fact,2 and 3 are linked,why no returns;
how to get returns?
thanks

url:http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qwdh4p

Comment: Can you set up an example using the neo4j console: http://console.neo4j.org/

Comment: i have edit the post and add the data set.

Comment: url:http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qwdh4p