# Why is cypher1's result different from cypher2's result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

cypher1:`start n=node(1,2,3),n1=node(1,2,3) match n-[r]-n1 return n,n1;`

cypher2:`start n=node(1,2,3),n1=node(3,2,1) match n-[r]-n1 return n,n1;`

node 2 and node 3 is linked,but cypher1 cannot get the relationship between 2 and 3; why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cypher get relationships between same nodes,but lose some relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560811/cypher-get-relationships-between-same-nodes-but-lose-some-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a bug report that has a similar scenario described:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/897

Feel free to chime in there if you have more example data.